# Crystal Reports/FormatEditor/Display String formula: How to format data

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to specify a formula for the display string property of an object on my report, however I want to use it to format the data that would otherwise show up if I were not using this formula.  Is there a keyword or anything I can reference within the formula that represents what would normally be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem this is possible as far as I've been able to tell.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to create a formula field and reference your database field within it:

for summarized fields, I use min(@cellVal) in the crosstab:

```
dim cVal as number

    cval =  {vw_rpt_waitlist.CountOfRecipientID}

    if cval < 0 then
        formula = " "
    elseif cval = 0 then
        formula = ""
    elseif cval < 5 then
        formula = "< 5"
    else
        formula =  cstr(cval,0,",")
    end if
```

and in the rows list, to modify the sorting:

```
if {vw_rpt_waitlist.SupportCode} < 100 then
    formula = {vw_rpt_waitlist.description}
else
    formula = "z" + totext({vw_rpt_waitlist.SupportCode}) + {vw_rpt_waitlist.description}
end if
```

Comment: Unfortunately that would defeat the purpose in this case.  My report is grouped a certain way so that I can't do a running total on a particular field the way I'd like to, however cross-tab's do their own grouping and if I could do a calculation based on the result of what is in the cross-tab field then I could get what I want... which is why I wish I had a way to access that number from within my formula.

Comment: there are usually lots of results in a cross-tab.  can you provide more information about what you're doing?

Comment: I.e. There's no way for me to get the cross tab to get me the result I want because your options are limited to simple aggregates and not formulas in the wizard.  However, I can't get the number I need *without* the cross-tab's help b/c of the way my data is grouped.  Hence why I wish I could just manipulate the data the cross-tab produces since it gets me half way there.

Comment: you can add a formula into your crosstab.  For one of my reports, I have them in the rows list and in the summarized fields list.

Comment: Well the question is fairly simple: When I format an object it applies my settings to what's already being displayed... unless I use a formula in the 'Display String' option in which case it just ignores what it would have displayed and displays the result of my formula. But how can I manipulate what it would have displayed from within my formula? I don't think it's possible but I was just hoping someone might know.  I've actually already solved my problem by doing the calculations I need in the query to begin with but I would still love to know the answer to my question for future reference.

Comment: Beth, I know I can use a formula in the cross-tab but the problem is that I can't get the number I need with a formula because it would require me to do a running total on data that isn't grouped in the correct way to do so.  But the cross-tab will get me the result I need and I just need to divide that result by another number which is why I wanted to use a formula on the cross-tab's result rather than use a formula in the cross-tab.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Well, you'd have to find a way to identify the single result you wanted out of the many cell values the crosstab returns.

Comment: +1 for trying, and because that info may be helpful to someone else.

Comment: Could you use the sum() function in your formula?  You should be able to specify the grouping independently of the report's groupings.

Comment: No, the cells show me labor dollars paid and I just need that number to be divided by net sales.  I'm not looking to do something with one particular cell but to all of them.

Comment: If I could do Sum(Distinct field) then that would work but Crystal doesn't provide that option.  We're getting off topic from the actual question and I've already solved the problem another way.  Thanks for your help though.